# Probability function of X and Y when two balls are drawn with no replacement

Tags: probability, random-variables

Two balls are drawn at random from a box containing ten balls numbered 0, 1, ... , 9. Let random variable X be the larger of the numbers on the two balls and random variable Y be their total.

Tabulate the probability function of X and of Y if the sampling is without replacement.

The answer to this question is $P(X=x, T=t) = \frac x{45}$ for $x= 1, 2, ..9, t=0, 1,...,x-1$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem because I'm not familiar with incorporating two random variables into one single probability function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
If I were to repeat this exact same experiment, but WITH replacement, would the process go something like this:

There are $10^2 = 100$ ways to randomly pick 2 balls with replacement out of the 10.
Then for $P(X=x)$, if we have 9 for example, we could have $(0,9), (1,9), ... , (9,9)$ ways, so there are 10 ways. Then if we have 8, we'd have $(0,8),...,(8,8)$ so 9 ways.
Thus, $P(X=x)=\frac{x+1}{100}$.
Next, the values for Y (the total sum of the two numbers) would be in the range of ${x, x+1, ..., 2x}$. Since they are uniformly distributed with the same probability, we would have:
$P(Y=y|X=x)= \frac1{2x-x+1} = \frac1{x+1}$
Thus, $P(X=x, Y=y) = \frac1{x+1} * \frac{x+1}{100} = \frac1{100}$ 
for $x=0, 1, ... , 9$ and $y={x, x+1, ... , 2x}$.

Would the above be correct?

Comment: What is T, should it be Y?

Answer (score 1):

There are $$\dbinom{10}{2}=\dfrac{10!}{8!2!}=\dfrac{10\cdot9}{2}=45$$ equiprobable possible ways to draw to balls at random from the box.

Now, there are $9$ ways that $X=9$, these are the pairs $(1,9), (2,9), \ldots, (8,9)$, $8$ ways that $X=8$, these ar the pairs $(1,8), (2,8), \ldots, (7,8)$ and so on, hence $$P(X=x)=\dfrac{x}{45}$$ for $x=0, 1, 2,\ldots, 9$. Moreover, if you know that $X=9$ then there is exactly $1$ way that $Y=10$ (if the other ball is equal to $1$), exactly $1$ way that $Y=11$ (if the other ball is equal to $2$) and so on. In total, given $X=x$, $Y$ can take only values in $\{x,x+1,\ldots, x+x-1\}$ with equal probability, that is $Y|X=x$ is uniformly distributed in $\{x,x+1,\ldots,2x-1\}$. Hence, $$P(Y=y|X=x)=\dfrac{1}{2x-1-(x-1)}=\dfrac{1}{x}$$ for $y=x,x+1,\ldots x+x-1$. Thus, $$P(X=x, Y=y)=P(Y=y|X=x)\cdot P(X=x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\dfrac{x}{45}=\dfrac{1}{45}$$ for $x=0,1,2\ldots,9$ and $y=x,x+1,\ldots,2x-1$.

---

To check whether the above expression is true you can sum up all the probabilities and see if they add up to 1. Indeed, you have that $$\sum_{x=0}^{9}\sum_{y=x}^{2x-1}\dfrac{1}{45}=\sum_{x=0}^{9}(2x-1-x+1)\dfrac{1}{45}=\sum_{x=0}^{9}\dfrac{x}{45}=\dfrac{9(9+1)}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{45}=1$$

---

Concerning your edit:

There are $10^2 = 100$ ways to randomly pick 2 balls with replacement out of the 10.
Then for $P(X=x)$, if we have 9 for example, we could have $(0,9), (1,9), ... , (9,9)$ *but also $(9,0),(9,1), ldots, (9,8)$* ways (note the before we did not write $10\cdot9=90$ ways, but 45), so there are $9+1+9$ ways. Then if we have $8$, we'd have $(0,8),...,(8,8)$ *but also (8,0),\ldots,(8,7)*so $(8+1+8)$ ways.
Thus, $P(X=x)=\frac{2x+1}{100}$. *Indeed summning up now these probabilities, you can see that they sum up to $1$. Before they did not!*
Next, the values for Y (the total sum of the two numbers) would be in the range of ${x, x+1, ..., 2x}$ *true!*. Since they are uniformly distributed with the same probability, we would have:
$$P(Y=y|X=x)= \frac1{2x-x+1} = \frac1{x+1}$$ for $y=x, x+1,\ldots, 2x$.
Thus, $$P(X=x, Y=y) = \frac1{x+1} * \frac{2x+1}{100} = \frac{2x+1}{100(x+1)}$$ 
for $x=0, 1, ... , 9$ and $y={x, x+1, ... , 2x}$. *Now again sum these probabilities up to check if the result is $1$. You have $$\sum_{x=0}^{9}\sum_{x}^{2x}\frac{2x+1}{100(x+1)}=\sum_{x=0}^{9}(x+1)\cdot\frac{2x+1}{100(x+1)}=\sum_{x=0}^{9}\frac{2x+1}{100(x+1)}=1$$ from above.*

Comment: Wow, this explanation is perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome dude!

Comment: Could you do me a huge favour and see if my edit above regarding repeating the experiment, but WITH replacement this time would be correct?

Comment: @E46 You had one mistake in $P(X=x)$. You could have avoided it if you checked whether the sum of the $P(X=x)$ is 1 or not.  Otherwise it was very good!